# AngularJs not working in a simple project

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a simple helloworld with angular But I cant see result from it! 
My angular.min.js is in the html file and it loads correctly in browser.
my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
    </head>

<body>
    <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HelloWorldCtrl($scope){
            $scope.helloMessage = "Hello Mohammad";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result : {{helloMessage}}

Comment: where is your `ng-app`? you have to initialize angular before it can parse expressions.

Comment: Start here: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: if recent version, global functions no longer supported for controllers and you have no `ng-app`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ng-app needs to be there, if you have any module then you can give ng-app="modulename" or you can just use ng-app to auto-bootstrap. it tells browser that you are bootstrapping an angular.js application

```
 <html ng-app>
```

**Update:** With angular 1.3 you can no longer use global controller declaration on the global scope. you have to use controller declaration as

```
 angular.module('myapp', []).controller('HelloWorldCtrl', function(){
    $scope.helloMessage = "Hello Mohammad";
 });
```

**Working Demo:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myapp">
    <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>
    
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       angular.module('myapp', []).controller('HelloWorldCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.helloMessage = "Hello Mohammad";
      });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I copy your code But again result = {{helloMessage}} !!!!

Comment: what version you are using can you provide fiddle

Comment: @mohammad see working demo in updated answer

Comment: Now work !! But why I cant set src to local .js file ?!?!?!

Comment: @mohammad you can set src to local js, it will work fine as well :)

Comment: I use  AngularJS v1.3.10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69688/discussion-between-mohammad-and-a-b).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ng-app and you need to declare the controller:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl as ctrl">{{ctrl.HelloMessage}}</h1>
<script
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js">
</script>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('HelloWorldCtrl', [function() {
       this.HelloMessage = 'Hello';
  }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above works and has been tested and works.

Comment: when I set src to site it work !! why I cant use it local ? I use  AngularJS v1.3.10

Comment: In your example your code expects angular.min.js to be in the same folder as your HTML file. If that is not the case you need to provide the proper path. Sounds like angular isn't being seen.